# How to hide startmenu - Windows buttom straight to typing in search bar - Win10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

I want to hide the startmenu buttom. I never use it at all I just go straight to search (Cortana thingie but without internet search or assistance) and type what I want).

Now it would be much more productive, if the Windows key would just go straight to search and ready to type.

Hope I can do this by some registry-tweaking, I dont really want any more programs.

btw: i disabled the bar when i first installed win10, now i only have to icon in my taskbar. how can i enable the bar again?

Thanks for your time :)

edit: I use win + s atm for this but it's a very unintuitive gesture for me + i want startmenu buttom gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck. When hitting the Start button (or the Start key on your keyboard), it is already programmed to allow for searching right away.

For instance, hit the start button, and start typing "Explorer" and it will automatically start searching. No need to press Win + S

Comment: thanks for that :D
i was wondering why they hid the bar at the buttom, now it makes sense

Comment: Yeah, Windows has been doing this (Start button or key allows you to start typing to search immediately) since Vista. For me, that feature alone made Vista better than XP; I use the keyboard a lot and it was finally easy to launch arbitrary programs that way. It was also the only way to make the Win8.x Start screen tolerable, although 8.0 did this stupid thing where it segregated "apps", "settings", and "files" results so you had to click between the result categories.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide de Start button anyway, the only option is using another program. You can use 7+ Taskbar Tweaker, it's a very simple and small program, and allows you, among other options, to hide it checking the "Hide Start button" checkbox in the main window.

[image: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker Options]

Here's a description from the webpage:

> 7+ Taskbar Tweaker allows you to configure various aspects of the Windows taskbar.
>   Most of the configuration options it provides can’t be tweaked using the taskbar properties or the registry.
>
> It provides options like disabling grouping, middle-click to close, etc.
>   The tweaker is designed for Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker